# How to use pouchdb-gql?

Tags: group-by, couchdb, pouchdb, gql

I want to use groupBy clause on a pouchdb query. As per the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-gql the code goes like this:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native';
var GQL = require('GQL');
PouchDB.plugin({ gql: GQL });
db.gql({select: "count(*)", groupBy: "columnX"},
function(err, results) {
   console.log(results);
});
```

I get "Unable to resolve module `GQL`". Tried replacing the GQL with "pouchdb-gql", I get db.gql is not a function. Please help.

Is there a way to achieve "groupBy" using pouchdb-find?

Comment: It doesn't seems maintained and there is already [one similar issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/GQL/issues/24) with not response so far.

Comment: @AlexisCôté, thanks for that. You know any package which can serve my need?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to use map/reduce or pouchdb-find. What you're trying to achieve is easily doable without extra libraries. With map/reduce, this is pretty easy. You map all documents that has columnX and you reduce with _count

Comment: @AlexisCôté, thanks for that hint. Referred http://acdcjunior.github.io/querying-couchdb-pouchdb-map-reduce-group-by-example.html